# Can't set view attributes programmatically

Tags: java, android

From my main activity, I'm trying to set attributes for some view objects. I grabbed these views from another fragment so I had to use layout inflator.

For some reason the attributes are not setting. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BluetoothSerialListener, BluetoothSerialRawListener, BluetoothDeviceListDialog.OnDeviceSelectedListener {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 1;
    private BluetoothSerial bluetoothSerial;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private Button bluetoothButton;
    private TextView batteryPercent;

    private View vBatteryLevelOne;
    private View vBatteryLevelTwo;
    private View vBatteryLevelThree;

    private String batteryLevelMsg;
    private float recvBatteryLevel;
    private int convBatteryLevel;
    private float batteryMax;
    private float batteryMin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        bindViews();

        bluetoothSerial = new BluetoothSerial(this, this);

        batteryLevelMsg = "%";
        batteryMax = 4.2f;
        batteryMin = 3.2f;

        //using layout inflator to get reference to views on tab1dashboard
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1_dashboard, null);

        vBatteryLevelOne = v.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevelOne);
        vBatteryLevelTwo = v.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevelTwo);
        vBatteryLevelThree = v.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevelThree);
        batteryPercent = v.findViewById(R.id.battery_percentage);

        vBatteryLevelOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vBatteryLevelTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        vBatteryLevelThree.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        bluetoothSerial.setup();
        updateBluetoothState();
    }
```

Comment: What did you mean by  attributes are not setting?

Comment: @JohnJoe, so for example, initially I have the visibility of batteryLevelOne, Two and Three set to invisible using the layout file. In the onCreate() method I'm setting them to visible, but when I run the app they remain visible. Same for my 'batteryPercent' one, I set the text, but it remains with the old text it had in the layout file.

Comment: Also I'm using these attribute changes in the onCreate method to test, initially I have another method that runs through some if conditions before changing the attribute values. I know it goes through the if statement, but the attributes weren't setting, so I tried in the onCreate method to no avail

Comment: You have set  `Two` and `Three` to invisible in layout file, but you set them visible in `onCreate`, thats why they will be visible

Comment: You want them to be visible or invisible ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant they remain INVISIBLE. That was my mistake. I expect them to be visible since I am setting them to be visible in onCreate.

Comment: Have you tried remove the invisible in layout and see whether they are visible?

Comment: So the behaviour I want is for them to initially be invisible. I have another method that makes them visible as certain conditions are met, however even when they were met I realized . I only put them in the onCreate method to see if the attributes were changing at all, and they're not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190065/discussion-between-als26-and-john-joe).

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason the attributes are not setting....

From the project you posted in `github`, this is `SectionsPagerAdapter` class

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments.add(new Tab1Dashboard());
        fragments.add(new Tab2Settings());
    }
        ....
}
```

Two fragments has been added into this class. So if you want to change the visibility in `Tab1Dashboard`, you should modify inside the `Tab1Dashboard` class, but **not** inside `MainActivity` class.

```
public class Tab1Dashboard extends BaseFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1_dashboard, container, false);
        // change the visibility here    
        View batteryOne = rootView.findViewById(R.id.batteryLevelOne);
        batteryOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```